# ENOENT err: no such file or directory, mkdir. This is related to npm not being able to find a file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cache-control, mkdir, enoent

I am getting this error for long, I have already reinstalled nodejs and reactjs more than 10 times, still nothing changed. My npm commands are also not working neither I am able to create a new app. I have tried "npm cache clean", "npm config edit", "npm cache clean --force", "npm audit" etc, but none responded. Please suggest me some way to resolve this issue!![This is the screenshot of the error.

```
    C:\Windows\system32>cd..
    C:\Windows>cd..
    C:\>d:
    D:\>cd react
    D:\react>npx create-react-app my-app
```

Even this failed to work.

I tried all the possible debugging methods, I had searched till now but none worked and I even installed and uninstalled node js so many times, even downloading node js apk didn't worked.

Comment: i'm guessing it's because you are on windows. have you tried running the command in bash?

Comment: bash is also not recognized as a command in my window.